# the different output of rare traditional Chinese with python running on Windows10 and Linux

Tags: python, windows

I use Python3 code `print(u'')`running respectively on windows10 and Linux.

The Linux shows the supposed result'', but the windows shows the '口口'。

At first, I thought it was because the window system language was simplified Chinese, so I changed it with traditional Chinese(Taiwan). But still it didn't work. I have tried a lot of methods, including codec.encode() and codec.decode(),but all failed.

Now my question is: how to show the supposed result'' on windows?

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you write the contents to a file? Because it might be the _Win_ console that's not able to "render" the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is the same. Read the file and the window output is just '口口'

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have tried all the possible encoding, but that does not work. Maybe the word is too rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

Each character cell in the Windows console contains a [single 16-bit character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str) (`WCHAR`), which limits the console to the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), i.e. the first 65,535 code points up to U+00FFFF. The character "" is U+02976B, which has to be encoded as a pair of UTF-16 surrogate codes (U+00D865 and U+00DF6B) and stored in two consecutive character cells. Individually, surrogate codes are not valid Unicode characters. Typically they display as an empty box, or some other default glyph.

The surrogate pair can be copied from the console to the clipboard and pasted in another window. If the target window supports rendering non-BMP characters, then it should display properly as "".